# to forget would be to condone?

Tags: meaning

> Our answer is this: So long as the nation in whose name and by whose hands these atrocities have been committed has not herself solemnly cast from her the scoundrels who dragged her into such decadence, we shall consider that it would betray our martyrs for us even to rub shoulders with their executioners, and that until the day arrives--if it ever does arrive--of a striking moral repentance, **to forget would be to condone**.

It's the last part of "Their Crimes" <1917>, regarding German atrocities during 1914 invasion.

Particularly the last sentence looks pretty odd to me.
(The text is a public domain, and it's translated from French, but no French
text is available right now.)

The last part means "just forget or ignore the past incidents until German repents is permissible or acceptable"?

But it's not very logical, I think.

I really don't understand.
Please help me!

Comment: It means they should never forget, because forgetting would be a tacit acceptance of the atrocities that were committed.

Comment: Did you consult your English dictionary to learn about the verb _"to condone"_? What did your dictionary tell you about this verb?

Comment: @P.E.Dant I think the parsing is the problem. Compare German "X ist zu Y", meaning that it's possible or fitting to do Y to X. That logic seems to produce the reading the asker arrived at — "forgetting is (a thing) to condone; forgetting is to be condoned".

Comment: @LukeSawczak In that case, the reader should forget all about German and learn about the particle _to_ as a marker of the English infinitive. That is why I mention an _English_ dictionary. (Or nag about it it, as some might say.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky part of English- it is a philosophical statement rather than an instruction.

> To Forget

This is the possibility, and the major operative. 'To Forget' is a possibility- another, less poetic translation would be 'If You Forget'.
This alternate interpretation is why an infinitive is used- an infinitive is a possibility- you could forget, you are not being told to forget.

> Would Be To Condone

This is how you tell it's not an instruction. 'Would' is not telling you to do something. It's saying that *if* you were to forget, then you would condone, or allow the tragedy to continue.
It shows a willingness to allow the tragedy to go unpunished (if you forget).

As such, another interpretation is 'If you forget, you allow the tragedy to happen again'.

Comment: There's a helpful nugget here, your observation that it's the same as "If you forget, you condone."

Comment: Why are infinitives used? What is the meaning of _would_ here? Does it mean volition, or willingness, or preference? We don't have the original text (which is likely to be _"Oublier c'est tolérer"_) from which to translate, so you can't present a "better translation." What you present is an _interpretation_.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Sorry, I'm new here; I'm editing in your comments. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1):

You have correctly understood the meaning of the words "forget" and "condone". But you have not parsed the syntax correctly.

When we use two infinitives, X and Y, in the structure "To X is to Y," **we are saying that the two actions are equivalent**, or that X entails Y.

One example from popular culture:

> To know her is to love her. ([The Beatles](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjXpOqV9ILVAhUp6YMKHfDZAOoQyCkIKzAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DYEoR-oNs4ow&usg=AFQjCNHQSQQ-6e1QyelMS0dgK914x0Q-qQ))

Here are two ways to paraphrase that sentence, in case they help:

> Knowing her means loving her.
>
> If you know her, then you must love her.

So we can see that this last line of the text means this:

> **If we forget** the atrocities, **then we will have condoned** the atrocities.

It's implied that condoning is unacceptable. Therefore, forgetting is also unacceptable.

This structure is very common in French, and it was almost certainly written the same way in the original. But it's not rare in English either.